# Как приложение под Gear VR переделать под Android?

Tags: unity3d

Сделал своё приложение на Unity для очков виртуальной реальности Samsung Gear VR. Хотелось бы сделать версию для Андроид, чтобы любой Android-пользователь смог использовать данное приложение, а не только пользователи sgs 6/7 + gear vr. Что для этого нужно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Поменяйте платформу в BuildSettings на Android и нажмите кнопку "Switch Platform" и Unity вам сама подскажет что не будет работать на выбранной платформе. вам нужно будет подправить проблемные куски, чтобы приложение запускалось на Android. Ну а дальше останется сделать интерфейс подходящий для разных устройств и размеров экрана и вроде бы все.

Comment: Видимо, вы плохо знаете ньюансы разработки под Gear VR. При разработке под Gear VR вы и так работаете над проектом под андроид, только предварительно импортировав package с SDK, скачанные с официального сайта.

Comment: тогда объясните в чем проблема? нужно использовать другое SDK?